# Where is string stored in solidity storage?

Tags: solidity, storage, string, keccak

I'm trying to check where is stored a string in **storage in Solidity**.

For testing this I'm using this code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;

contract AssemblyString {
    string s; // slot 0

    function set(string calldata _s) external {
        s = _s;
    }

    function get(uint i) public view returns (bytes32){
        bytes32 r;
        assembly {
            r := sload(i) //we load the slot number i
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

If I set string less than 31 bytes works fine as [solidity specifies:](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.4/miscellaneous.html#bytes-and-string)

1. Deploy contract
2. set("ether")
3. get(0)

Output: 0x657468657200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a

The first part stands for the **encoded string**:  0x6574686572 equals "ether".
The second part is the **size*2**: 0xA equals 10 in decimal. *(ether has 5 letters, then 5 times 2 equals 10)*
All the zeros in between are padded to reach 32 bytes long.

---

**But!** if I set string more than 31 bytes, I can't find the string.
As the specification says, the data of the string is contained in the keccak256(slot).

When I search for
[keccak256(0)](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) = 044852b2a670ade5407e78fb2863c51de9fcb96542a07186fe3aeda6bb8a116d
[To decimal](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html): 
1937035142596246788172577232054709726386880441279550832067530347910661804397

Output: 0x0

But if I debug the contract in [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org), I found that the data is stored always in key 0x290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563,
dec: 18569430475105882587588266137607568536673111973893317399460219858819262702947
and the string is stored at that position.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

running this in javascript:

```js
const utils = require('web3-utils'); // npm install web3
console.log(utils.soliditySha3(0x0))
>> 290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e563
```

Also with this code in solidity:

```
function test() public pure returns(bytes32){
    bytes memory a = new bytes(32);
    return keccak256(a);
}
```

It works!